# Question on Proper Associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many, has-many-through

Take for example this situation.

You have 3 models:

1. Poet - Represents the author of a poem
2. Poem - Represents a poem written by a Poet
3. Printing - Represents a printed publication of any sort containing the Poet's Poem.

Right off the bat poet and poem are obvious:

- Poet `has_many` poems
- Poem `belongs_to` poet

It becomes confusing for me when dealing with the Printing model.

In this case a Printing, in some sense, belongs to both the poet and poem.  You could say a poet has_many printings or a poem has_many printings which makes sense but going the inverse route is tricky...

What about a situation where some magazine or book printed 5 poems from one poet? OR, one of the poems is published in 10 different magazines?

It almost seems as if the Printing itself "belongs to many" poems or poets.  I know this is wrong, but i'm just trying to articulate the point.

So the answerable question is this:
How would you set up these relationships?  Specifically, what would the model and database table look like AND how would you use them to access associated data?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What about a situation where some magazine or book printed 5 poems from one poet?

Remeber if you have a poet that has many poems and printing that has many poems as well you can alway get the poet.

Poet.poems.first.printings would return all the printings of the poets first poem

or you could do Printing.poems.first.poet  This way you could get the poet of the first poem in the printing.

> How would you set up these relationships? Specifically, what would the model and database table look like AND how would you use them to access associated data?

I would set it up like this

```
Poet :has_many poems
poem :belongs_to poet
poem :has_and_belongs_to_many printings
printing :has_many poems
```

Because you are using a has_and_belogs_to_many association you need a join table, for poems and printings

you would have migration that looks like this

```
CreatePoemsPrintingJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :poems_printings, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :poem_id
      t.integer :printing_id
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :poems_printings
  end
end
```

The other tables are pretty easy

```
CreateTablePoems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :poems, do |t|
    t.integer :poet_id
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :poems
  end
end

CreateTablePoets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :poets do |t|
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :poems
  end
end

CreateTablePrintings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :printings do |t|
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :printings
  end
end
```

Comment: it would get trickier if a poem could appear in many printings, not sure if that is the case here?

Comment: That is exactly the case and i just updated the text right as you guys posted answers :X

Comment: I would suggest that a poem `has_and_belongs_to_many :printings` in that case

Comment: I agree, I always forget habtm, I updated my answer to reflect it

Comment: Would you be willing to add what the DB tables should look like for your solution?  I'm assuming it's pretty simple, but just want to make sure.

Comment: agree - check out rails guides - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association

Comment: I added migrations, but I really just threw them together so don't copy and paste them.  Also in rails dont explicitly create tables always use migrations.  It allows for you to make mistakes

Comment: Austinbv thank you very much. I will be trying a few things and ultimately selecting your answer but i was first wondering -- why would you not go with a `has_many :through` association?  Would that not be a more flexible alternative?

Comment: again you should read the rails guides linked above, the relationship you are trying to construct from my understanding is not a through, both are acceptable paths. there is a much better description than I can give you on the [rails guides here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many). Also remember if you like my answer Accept It! glad I could help

Comment: I actually did read the guide but i didn't see the 2.8 section where they are compared thanks again.